# Websocket Phonegap for Android Error

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, websocket

I am trying to implement websocket API in the HTML5 that I built,
but apparently when I display the web within Android using the PhoneGap,
it doesn't support Websocket standard (both Phonegap/cordova and the android browser),
so I tried to use plugin:
[websocket android phonegap by anismiles](https://github.com/anismiles/websocket-android-phonegap)

It should work actually, what I did was:

- copy the java source to the phonegap project inside eclipse
- create websocketlistener that extend websocket
- attach the websocketfactory to webview (inside the org.apache.cordova.example
- and create the websocket client in my javascript
- I have the websocket.js and cordova-2.5.0.js attached inside the HTML script

The problem is it always generate an error like it doesn't recognize websocket type

so I tried to wrap it inside the try catch function:

```
try
{
//writeToScreen("websocket");
var wsocket = new WebSocket("122.168.196.27:8081/");
}
catch(err)
{
alert(err.message);
}
```

and I get the err.message:

> Object [object Object] has no method 'getInstance'

I tried to modify, but none has worked so far,
any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

try this, change the "targetSdkVersion" form 17 to 15 or lower than 15.

Comment: Please try to add more context to your answer. For instance, why would lowering the version could make a difference.